# High performance apply on group by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, apply

I need to calculate percentile on a column of a pandas dataframe. A subset of the dataframe is as below:

[image: df]

I want to calculate the 20th percentile of the SaleQTY, but for each group of ["Barcode","ShopCode"]:
so I define a function as below:

```
def quant(group):
    group["Quantile"] = np.quantile(group["SaleQTY"], 0.2)
    return group
```

And apply this function on each group pf my sales data which has almost 18 million rows and roughly 3 million groups of ["Barcode","ShopCode"]:

```
quant_sale = sales.groupby(['Barcode','ShopCode']).apply(quant)
```

That took 2 hours to complete on a windows server with 128 GB Ram and 32 Core.
It make not sense because that is one small part of my code. S o I start searching the net to enhance the performance.
I came up with "numba" solution with below code which didn't work:

```
from numba import njit, jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def quant_numba(df):
    final_quant = []
    for bar_shop,group in df.groupby(['Barcode','ShopCode']):
        group["Quantile"] = np.quantile(group["SaleQTY"], 0.2)
        final_quant.append((bar_shop,group["Quantile"]))
    return final_quant    
result = quant_numba(sales)
```

It seems that I cannot use pandas objects within this decorator.
[image]

I am not sure whether I can use of multi processing (which I'm unfamiliar with the whole concept) or whether is there any solution to speed up my code. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One approach is to partition your dataset on barcode/shopcode and use multiprocessing to apply quant function on the partitioned datasets. Other way is to use something like Modin/Dask/Celery or Use Spark to bring out the big guns

Comment: Have you tried keeping it simpler and doing something like: `df['Quantile'] = df.groupby(['Barcode', 'Shopcode'])['SaleQTY'].transform('quantile', q=0.2)` ?

Comment: @skybunk Thanks... should I explicitly define each partition? would you please give me a hint on defining the partitions? Then I think I can get the help of map_partition. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Barcode', 'Shopcode'])['SaleQTY'].quantile(0.2)
```

Or like montioned @Jon Clements for new columns filled by percentiles use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Quantile'] = df.groupby(['Barcode', 'Shopcode'])['SaleQTY'].transform('quantile', q=0.2)
```

Comment: What I was thinking... but then wasn't sure if what they were trying to do was transform (as I put in a comment) or this... it's more likely this I guess :)

Comment: @JonClements - thank you, tested and working for new column nice.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael  ...to overcome my curiosity... what is behind this simple apply a built in function on groups, which makes the whole process to be completed in less than a minute? Cause in my defined "quant" function, I also used numpy built in function(np.quantile)

Comment: @mpy - I think reason is pandas are optimalized functions per groups in numba, numpy, so very fast.

Comment: @mpy `apply` is generic, has additional Python call overhead and it can return different result types that need to be broadcast/expanded etc... and because of that flexibility it has quite a fair bit of work as well as producing quantiles it needs to do to produce the end result... However, the builtins have a well defined result and operator more at the bare bones level so can be much much faster

Answer (score 1):

There is a inbuilt function in panda called quantile().

quantile() will help to get nth percentile of a column in df.

Doc reference [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html)

geeksforgeeks example [reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-quantile/)